# Why does fftfreq produce negative values?

Tags: python, numpy

From the documentation for [fftfreq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html):

```
>>> signal = np.array([-2, 8, 6, 4, 1, 0, 3, 5], dtype=float)
>>> fourier = np.fft.fft(signal)
>>> n = signal.size
>>> timestep = 0.1
>>> freq = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=timestep)
>>> freq
array([ 0.  ,  1.25,  2.5 ,  3.75, -5.  , -3.75, -2.5 , -1.25])
```

Why are there negative values in the output array?

I am trying to produce a plot of amplitude vs frequency. I can get the amplitude by running the `abs()` function over the elements of `fourier`, but how do I convert `freq` into a series of frequencies that I can use as an x-axis when plotting `fourier`?

Comment: Those are your frequencies for the x-axis. If you only want to plot the positive frequencies then filter/truncate them out

Comment: Are you asking why there are negative frequencies in Fourier analysis or why there are negative frequencies in that particular example?

Comment: @Will I wasn't aware that direction was encoded in the result. Thanks, I'll just truncate the outputs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's inherent to FFT algorithm.
The second half of FFT array is the conjugate of the first half, so don't contain any new information.

To visualize the spectrum, just use the first half.

```
f=freq[:n/2]
s=abs(fourier[:n/2])
plot(f,s)
```

Comment: should be n//2 + 1?

Comment: It's actually the consequence a sine/cosine is the difference/sum of two conjugate phasors, as described by [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry). This same formula also explains why the output of a DFT (FFT) is made of complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The FFT is just a computationally efficient version of the DFT.  [By definition of the DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) the terms in frequency space are given by (Eq. 1 in the link)

```
X_k = sum n=0 to N - 1 x_n exp(-i*2*pi*k*n/N),
```

where N is the number of elements in the list to be transformed and x_n are the elements of the list.  If you plug in k = N - 1 you'll find

```
X_(N-1) = sum n=0 to N - 1 x_n exp(i*2*pi*n/N).
```

This is exactly equal to X_1 except for the sign in front of the frequency (2*pi*n/N).  The same holds for X_2 and X_(N-2), and so on. That is the source of the negative signs you are seeing in the second half of fftfreq.